# Hide and show slide arrows in slick slider

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

```js
 $('.slider-for').slick({
   slidesToShow: 1,
   slidesToScroll: 1,
   arrows: false,
   fade: true,
   asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
 });
 $('.slider-nav').slick({
   slidesToShow: 3,
   slidesToScroll: 1,
   asNavFor: '.slider-for',
   dots: true,
   focusOnSelect: true
 });
```

```css
body{
  background:#ccc;
}
.main {
  font-family:Arial;
  width:500px;
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
}
h3 {
    background: #fff;
    color: #3498db;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 2%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.js"></script>

<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick-theme.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />

<div class="main">
  <div class="slider slider-for">
    <div><h3>1</h3></div>
    <div><h3>2</h3></div>
    <div><h3>3</h3></div>
    <div><h3>4</h3></div>
    <div><h3>5</h3></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider slider-nav">
    <div><h3>1</h3></div>
    <div><h3>2</h3></div>
    <div><h3>3</h3></div>
    <div><h3>4</h3></div>
    <div><h3>5</h3></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using slick slider in website. Having problem to hide and show arrows on different slides. For example hide preview(left) arrow when there is 1st slide is active and hide next(right) arrow when there is last slide. Between 1st and last both arrows will be shown.

Answer (score 1):

`infinite` option has default = `true`. Setting it to false does what you want.

```js
 $('.slider-for').slick({
   slidesToShow: 1,
   slidesToScroll: 1,
   arrows: false,
   fade: true,
   asNavFor: '.slider-nav',
   infinite: false
 });
 $('.slider-nav').slick({
   slidesToShow: 3,
   slidesToScroll: 1,
   asNavFor: '.slider-for',
   dots: true,
   focusOnSelect: true,
   infinite: false
 });
```

```css
.slick-disabled:before {
  display: none;  
}
body{
  background:#ccc;
}
.main {
  font-family:Arial;
  width:500px;
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
}
h3 {
    background: #fff;
    color: #3498db;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 2%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.js"></script>

<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick-theme.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />

<div class="main">
  <div class="slider slider-for">
    <div><h3>1</h3></div>
    <div><h3>2</h3></div>
    <div><h3>3</h3></div>
    <div><h3>4</h3></div>
    <div><h3>5</h3></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider slider-nav">
    <div><h3>1</h3></div>
    <div><h3>2</h3></div>
    <div><h3>3</h3></div>
    <div><h3>4</h3></div>
    <div><h3>5</h3></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but some where its not set on my design.

Comment: I need like this: https://jsfiddle.net/e11t36L3/    But I have three slides in scroll.

Comment: Just edit the css selector `.slick-disabled:before` and add a rule `display: none;`